# return each and every values in for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-edittext

im using for loop to return values of edit text displayed in listview...the below code helps me to return only the last value of edit text...Instead i need to return all the edit text value each and every time it is looped..please help..thanks in advance

```
public String quantity() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
        View view = cartList.getChildAt(i);
        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
        string = editText.getText().toString();

    }
    return string;
}
```

I want to return the string value here

```
AddedCart += carts.getName() + "," + carts.getButton() + "," + quantity() + "," +carts.getPrice() + ",";
```

Comment: you can directly return whole arraylist instead of a string

Comment: how you want to return ? comma separated or Sum of quantity ?

Comment: Where you do you want to use all string?

Comment: the arraylist is the no. of quantity ordered for each product in a cart...if i return arraylist then i won't be able to identigy quantity for each product

Comment: the above code is edited please check

Comment: @MeenakshiRuby, Do you want to join all the string into one and then return it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can store all values in an ArrayList and can return that ArrayList from the method.

```
public ArrayList<String> quantity() {
    ArrayList<String> cartArray = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
        View view = cartList.getChildAt(i);
        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
        string = editText.getText().toString();
        cartArray.add(string);
    }
    return cartArray;
}
```

Comment: i tried this helped me a bit....for example arraylist takes up the value [4,2] in AddedCart += carts.getName() + "," + carts.getButton() + "," + arraylist + "," +carts.getPrice(); .........but i need it to take first 4 and then second iteration 2....how do i do it?

Comment: @MeenakshiRuby, In that case you need to call quantity() method 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Change your quantity method return arraylist.

```
public ArrayList<String> quantity() {
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
        View view = cartList.getChildAt(i);
        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
        string = editText.getText().toString();
        arraylist.add(string);
    }
    return arraylist;
}
```

call quantity method from your activity or fragment like

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
arraylist = quantity();
```